# NinePatchDrawable from Drawable.createFromPath or FileInputStream

Tags: android, drawable, nine-patch

I cannot get a nine patch drawable to work (i.e. it is stretching the nine patch image) when loading from either Drawable.createFromPath or from a number of other methods using an InputStream.

Loading the same nine patch works fine when loading from when resources.  Here's the methods I am trying:

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);

Drawable d = null;

//From Resources (WORKS!)
d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.test);

//From Raw Resources (Doesn't Work)
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test);
d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, null);

//From Assets (Doesn't Work)
try {
InputStream is = getResources().getAssets().open("test.9.png");
d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, null);
} catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

//From FileInputStream (Doesn't Work)
try {
FileInputStream is = openFileInput("test.9.png");
d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, null);
} catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

//From File path (Doesn't Work)
d = Drawable.createFromPath(getFilesDir() + "/test.9.png");


if (d != null) b.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

Answer (score 1):

I answered a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079868/create-a-ninepatch-ninepatchdrawable-in-runtime/5519768#5519768) about non-resource-based ninepatches. To read a file from within .apk archives, I use something like this:

```
String filepath = "com/kanzure/images/thx1138.png";
InputStream stream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filepath);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar problem. I'm trying to create a `NinePatchDrawable` from a `Bitmap` that I've retrieved over the network. I still haven't found a solution to that problem. Since the `Drawable.createFrom...` methods apparently doesn't work, my only option seems to be to understand how to format the nine-patch chunk, and to invoke the `NinePatch` constructor. See the [SO-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079868/create-a-ninepatch-ninepatchdrawable-in-runtime) for details.