# How to set size of nine-patch drawable programmatically in android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-drawable, nine-patch

This is how we can resize a normal bitmap drawable

```
 Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.error);
    Bitmap bm = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();

    error_indicator = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm.createScaledBitmap(bm, 50, 50, true));
```

But I want to know how to resize a nine patch drawable. since the above code doesnt works for me giving me ClassCastException saying NinePatchDrawable cannot be cast to BitmapDrawable.
[image: error drawable]

This is nine-patch drawable(hdpi).I have other resolutions icons too

Draw 9-patch tool screenshot

[image]

App Screenshot

[image]

Comment: nah that doesnt works..already tried it..

Comment: setBounds(): `Specify a bounding rectangle for the Drawable. This is where the drawable will draw when its draw() method is called.`

Comment: I have tried drawable.setBounds(top, left, right, bottom); . But this doesnt works for me.. infact my icon looks messed up..

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to resize my editext's error icon(drawable) using setError method but my I want to give my drawable a particular height and width programmatically. I dont want to use my drawable's original dimensions

Comment: so you are using TextView.setError(CharSequence, Drawable)? if so it shows the Drawable resized as set by setBounds()

Comment: yes I am using Edittext.. I tried setBounds but it is messing up icon instead of resizing..

Comment: messing up? if i use setBounds() then it is resizing, not messing up

Comment: I dont know.. but that is not working for me.. My icon is an exclamation inside circle but when I use setBounds it displays some weird starlike image..not working for me..

Comment: now run draw9patch tool and see if it looks as you want it to be

Comment: @pskink - what do you mean by exactly asking me to see if it looks as I want? I mean I havent used this tool much.. it looks the same as above when I opened it in the tool..

Comment: see the right scrolling view

Comment: There are 3.. none of them looks like the one above.. Do I have to change the patches?

Comment: the output is same as the previous one..

Comment: so whats modified 9 patch and the output?

Comment: will upload a screenshot of the tool

Comment: upload 9 patch and tho output of your app

Comment: This is the code I am using:
int left = 0;
 int top = 0;
 
 int right = 100;
 int bottom = 100;
 error_indicator.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);

Comment: so whats modified 9 patch and the output of your app?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63156/discussion-on-question-by-pooh1527-how-to-set-size-of-nine-patch-drawable-progra).

Comment: maybe you want to see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6828754/724913