# Downlaod drawables from server to reduce APK file size

Tags: android, apk, android-drawable, xml-drawable

To reduce the APK file size, I want to remove the drawables (images and XML files) from my project and download the proper ones from my server on the first app start.

The problem is how to load and use the downloaded drawables in my code?

This is what I found after some research:

- For normal images, I can use [`BitmapDrawable`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375166/android-drawable-images-from-url).
- For 9-patch images, I can use [`NinePatchDrawable`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284784/android-how-to-create-a-9patch-image-from-an-inputstream).

But I still don't know how to load and use XML drawables that have references to other drawables, like this:

```
<layer-list>
  <item>
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/other_drawable" />
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

Any thoughts on this or other effective ideas to reduce the APK file size would be appreciated.

*Notes:*

- The drawables make up most of the APK file size (20mb/25mb).
- I already compressed image files and I'm using ProGuard.

---

**Update:**

After some more research, it seems to me possible to load/use downloaded XML drawables after modifying them a little by using custom attributes for referenced drawables and a subclass of `Drawable` instead of native `BitmapDrawable`. So the above XML drawable example will become something like this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <item>
    <custom-bitmap custom:ref="other_drawable" />
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

Though, it's not a very easy solution and I'm not sure it's better than doing things manually.

References:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/glpdi0AdMzI
- https://code.google.com/p/adet/source/browse/trunk/AdetSample/res/drawable/svg_button.xml

Answer (score 2):

XML Files and drawables are only to help developers, these are not the essential part of the programming in android. If you want to download from server you can do this.
what you have to do is Create Layouts and other things manually in Java files.
i-e

```
RelativeLayout rl =new Relativelayout(Context);// To create Layout
Button button = new Button(Context); // Create Components Like this
button.setText("abc");// Set Properties
```

Now add components to layout as a child.

```
rl.addView(button,new          Layoutparams(Layoutparams.WRAP_CONTENT,Layoutparams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

In onCreate return this Layout!

For drawables include very important in your drawable and download others through HTTP Calls.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, almost everything we can do with XML drawables can be done programmatically, but I'm wondering here if I can load and use XML drawables at run time after downloading them without needing to redo everything manually.

Comment: @Hejazi I am pretty  sure it is not possible with xml drawables

Answer (score 2):

First of all, that size isn't too bad if your application have intense ui interaction. Also, in some moment the user will need download that drawables, why not in the installation from the google playstore?. Anyways, If you really want to do it, you can do the following:

For the reference in your layouts, you will need hook up from every widget that have a reference to a drawable and implement your own tag. For example, if you old layout looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/someImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/somePicture" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now should look like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.custom"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<com.example.custom.RemoteImageView
    android:id="@+id/someImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    custom:remoteSrc="somePicture" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Remember add the custom tag definition in your `attrs.xml`. In the implementation of the class you can get the image (if exist) from some cache like this:

```
public class RemoteImageView extends ImageView {

private String remoteSrc;
private DiskLruImageCache diskCache;

public RemoteImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public RemoteImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    diskCache = new DiskLruImageCache(this, "cache", 1024 * 1024 * 30, CompressFormat.PNG, 70);
    TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            R.styleable.RemoteImageView, 0, 0);

    try {
        remoteSrc = a.getString(R.styleable.RemoteImageView_remoteSrc);
        Bitmap cachedImage;
        if (!diskCache.containsKey(remoteSrc)) {
            //Download it from Internet and save it into the cache
            //...
            diskCache.put(remoteSrc, bitmapThatYouDownload);
        }
        cachedImage = diskCache.getBitmap(remoteSrc);
        //Use the cachedImage as the bitmap for this view.
    } finally {
        a.recycle();
    }
}

public RemoteImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

}
```

To see about `DiskLruImageCache` you can check this links:

[DiskLruCache](https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache)

You can do some tricks with this like have a two-levels cache, the first one with a memory cache and the second one with a disk cache. Already exist libraries that does stuff like this, but how you need your custom tags, you can either modify those libraries or use the cache library in your classes like I show you above.

---

For the `AnimationDrawable`'s like animation-list you will need build the animation in runtime. For example like this:

```
AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();
animation.addFrame(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),diskCache.get(myFirstFreame)), 100);
animation.addFrame(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),diskCache.get(mySecondFrame)), 1000);
animation.addFrame(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),diskCache.get(myThirdFrame)), 1000);
animation.setOneShot(false);

ImageView imageAnim =  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
imageAnim.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);
```

Remember check if `myFirstFrame`,`mySecondFrame` and `myThirdFrame` are already in the cache. If not then download them and add them.

Hope this help, but if I was you, I would keep that size, personally isn't so much, I've developed a tumblr client with a lot of animation and ui features, and the apk size was around 15 MiB.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I did some more research and updated the question to show what I found.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if your drawable goes this much (20MB) here i mean to drawable is **xml Files only**.
Coz these **can not be downloaded later**, *Have you properly optimize your code for Re-useability*?

but you are free with the Images/raw's like audio files or something like this

#### My Suggestions

**Note:** If you are looking for `downloadable xml drawables` then answer is no it is **not possible** it must be withing apk and also you can follow the following to optimize

- You shall download All of your Audio/images and other files on installation cause this is the only solution to reduce the apk size
- You can't do anything with your xml Drawables you will have to have with apk so you shall optimize code as much as possible.
- For xml Drawable you can look for Re-useability

As your question says how to use Downloaded drawable to you code

so the answer is You can not go with xml drawable but yes you can do these things with images
and there is clear method of setting `drawable` from file or creating `Bitmap` from file

Comment: The drawables are not only XML files, there are many normal/9-patch images too. After checking some solutions, it seems to me possible to load downloaded XML drawables on runtime after replacing `android:src` attribute with custom attribute and use a subclass of `Drawable`.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement you can not change the xml drawables at runtime.

Other that if you still need this functionality you can download it on your application's splash screen and set it runtime as you have suggest using BitmapDrawable.

But as per my opinion this is not right way to use this, as when you create your activity that time your view already render on setContentView(layoutID). So when you call your activity it will display the blank views without images.

And from other resources i have read that you can not change the resources file like drawable, raw,strings at runtime as it's id's can't create on runtime.

Comment: I'm already downloading most of the resources from my server on first app start. My problem was to find a simple way to load/use XML drawables that have references to other drawables, which now seems to me possible actually, but not that simple at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could use expansion files (see http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html) and move your resources there using the jobb tool (http://developer.android.com/tools/help/jobb.html).

You would still have to handle unavailable resources as long as the expansion file has not been downloaded though.

Comment: But I still don't know how to use the XML drawables I added to the expansion files.

Comment: You can mount the OBB file using StorageManager (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageManager.html)

Comment: But can I still have references to those drawables (as in the example in the question) after adding them to the OBB file?