# Is it possible to use a 9-slice image when loading an image from a file path using BitmapFactory

Tags: android, bitmap, android-image, android-resources, bitmapfactory

Normally an image which has been 9-sliced will stretch automatically if it is loaded from a resource. Is it possible to retain this functionality when loading the image using a file path and BitmapFactory?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this, but it seems as though you can just create a `NinePatchDrawable` with the `Bitmap`, check out [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/NinePatchDrawable.html).

Edit: Hmmm... it might not be as simple as it seems, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079868/create-a-ninepatch-ninepatchdrawable-in-runtime).

Answer (score 0):

"9-patch", but yes. See the [constructor for `NinePatch`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html#NinePatch%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20byte%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29).