# Set 9patch background dynamically

Tags: android, button, background, nine-patch

does anyone have tried to set 9Patch background of button dynamically? If it is important, button's width and height is set wrap_content

If yes, how have you solved the "black line" issue?

Thanks

Comment: don't really get what you are trying to ask here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5079868/543711

Comment: I need to change Button's background in run-time. The background is 9Patch. When I do so, I see that 9Patch doesn't work as it should

Comment: Check if your 9patch is correct. Did you do it with draw9patch?

Comment: In what way does it not "work as it should"?  Can you edit your question and put your patch 9 in there?

Answer (score 5):

If you are seeing the black dots you drew on the 9-patch image, it's because you have not pre-compiled your images.

To set 9-patch images as background at runtime, they have to be previously compiled, when the border is removed and encoded to a PNG chunk.

You can do that by inserting the .9.png images in the `res/drawable` folder of your application, compiling it and generating the .apk (on Eclipse, right click on your `project root > Android Tools > Export Unsigned Application Package`). Then unzip the .apk and you'll have the .9.png images with the 9-patch compiled data in them.

With your pre-compiled 9-patch images, do something like that to load your image:

```
private Drawable loadNinePatch(String path, Context context) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        byte[] chunk = bitmap.getNinePatchChunk();
        if(NinePatch.isNinePatchChunk(chunk)) {
            return new NinePatchDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap, chunk, new Rect(), null);
        } else return new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
}
```

and then set it as the background of your button:

```
button.setBackgroundDrawable(loadNinePatch("/data/data/your.app/files/button_background.9.png", context));
```

Comment: Great answer. Saved me a lot of time.