# Creating a 9 patch procedurally?

Tags: android, nine-patch, android-drawable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a NinePatch/NinePatchDrawable in runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079868/create-a-ninepatch-ninepatchdrawable-in-runtime)

I'm trying to create a 9 patch image procedurally but can't see how to do it.  Is there any way to take a normal PNG/JPG image and adapt it so that I can specify a center width and center height to generate a 9 patch drawable?

I was going to create a bitmap at runtime and add the black edge markers into the bitmap and create the 9 patch from this in the app but reading this thread it seems it's not possible due to additional magic data that is created by the resource compiler so any pointers?

[Google Groups Link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/fYmzquzM8Qo)

Essentially I know the image will be used for a button and will have 4, 4x4 corners that should not be stretched and the remaining pixels in the center are able to be stretched.

Comment: try this http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: try to use this link .. http://www.androiddom.com/2011/05/android-9-patch-image-tutorial.html

Comment: I think you can create the 9-patch by drawing on the Bitmap, but to use inside your application.Maybe you can find a solution on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/NinePatchDrawable.html

Comment: Thanks Padma, yes that's the answer and some