# convert base64 into 9 patch .png in android

Tags: php, android, json, nine-patch

I am trying to send several images that are found on my php server to my app. The images are 9 patch .png files. For that, on my server I am encoding with base64:

```
$img = fread(fopen($filepath, "r"), filesize($filepath));
$bin_image = base64_encode($img);
```

and later on I wrap it up as a json and send it to my app:

```
echo json_encode($response);
```

on my android app I am getting the image from the responded json :

```
public ServerMsg(JSONObject response, ServerResponseTags responseTag) throws JSONException {
    ...
    String image_str = response.getString(IMAGE);
    byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(image_str.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length);
    ...
}
```

the problem is that the image isn't presented as 9 patch png file as I needed. I know that I need to convert the bitmap image into png 9 patch file but I don't know how...
Any suggestions ?

Comment: a nine patch is a bitmap with extra chunk of info. you need to split these on the server, then use the NinePatch class to put them togeteher again.

Comment: OK... how do I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on this post :[Create a NinePatch/NinePatchDrawable in runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079868/create-a-ninepatch-ninepatchdrawable-in-runtime) and I used Brian Griffey class to convert bitmap into nine patch on the fly very easly...