# Scaling image without losing quality

Tags: android, nine-patch

Is it possible to scale image without loosing its quality?I have seen posts that say to use Ninepatch images but how can we download an image and convert it to ninepatch image so that i can show it in ImageView.
Is there any other way so that my images with smaller size can be scaled like in whats app

Comment: I think this'll help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079868/create-a-ninepatch-ninepatchdrawable-in-runtime/5519768#5519768

Comment: Creating 9-path. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html You should probably read about what one is, rather than just posting a question. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

Comment: You didn't really say what's the problem here.  What did you try? What did you get?  And what did you expect?  Upscale or downscale?

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you scale an image it's losing quality, the only thing you can do to keep the quality is keeping a copy of the original image (which doesn't make much sense since you can just load it again from resources).

If you mean the problem was that android was scaling your images (and changing the quality) you can put images on a folder named "raw" inside res.

Ninepatch images can be made manually by you, you just paint an image that has two extra pixels on width and two on height, and when you save it , name it something.9.png
if you want to know how to draw them correctly follow this: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: I want to fetch image from server and then convert it to ninepatch at runtime programmatically.